# Какие классы в C# нельзя наследовать?

Tags: c#

Запечатанные классы точно нельзя наследовать. Есть ли еще какие-то варианты?

Comment: Статические нельзя

Comment: абстрактные классы как раз можно ТОЛЬКО наследовать. Экземпляр создавать нельзя

Comment: @vmchar ну если нельзя создать экземпляр, это не значит что класс можно только наследовать)

Comment: @yolosora, а что с ним можно еще делать? :-)

Comment: @yolosora, да, можно еще с точки зрения полиморфизма использовать

Comment: @Grundy как минимум можно статические члены подергать! :D

Comment: Нельзя наследовать те, что не имеют неприватных конструкторов еще. Ну т. е. ограничения такого фактически нет, но чисто физически вы не сможете написать код наследника :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP *чисто физически вы не сможете написать код наследника :)* Смогу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя наследовать:

1. запечатанные классы (помеченные модификатором `sealed`)
2. классы с только`private` конструктором. За исключением подобного примера:

   ```
   namespace ConsoleCS
   {
     using System;
     public class Program
   {
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       BaseClass.DerivedClass dc = new BaseClass.DerivedClass();
       Console.WriteLine("\nDone.");
       Console.ReadLine();
   }

   public abstract class BaseClass
   {
       private BaseClass()
       {
           Console.WriteLine("base ctor");
       }

       public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
       {
           public DerivedClass() 
           {
               Console.WriteLine("derived ctor");
           }
       }
   } }}
   ```

   Имеется в виду, что наследовать можно, если класс вложенный. В других ситуациях не выйдет.
3. статические классы (помеченные модификатором `static`)

Comment: @АндрейNOP поправил, дельное замечание

Comment: @vmchar, АндрейNOP спасибо, очень полезно :)

Comment: На самом деле не наследовать можно, а именно получить доступ к приватному члену. Если класс не вложенный ошибка же не в наследовании, а в том, что нет доступа к конструктору. В остальных случаях ошибка именно о невозможности наследования.

Comment: *В других ситуациях не выйдет.* До C# 6 вызывать базовый конструктор вовсе не обязательно, а следовательно и его уровень доступа не является помехой. https://ideone.com/6xPB8k

Comment: @PetSerAl, вы уверены, что это документированное поведение? Больше похоже на баг. UB потом не вылезет? В любом случае я бы так писать не стал :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP *вы уверены, что это документированное поведение?* Что именно? Автор ответа утверждает, что невозможно унаследовать от класса с недоступным конструктором. Вот пример, что это не так: `class B { private B() { } } class C: B { C(): this(1) { } C(int i): this() { } }`. Спецификация лишь утверждает, что конструктор не может вызывать сам себе: `class A { A(): this() { } }` [CS0516](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/csharp/misc/cs0516.md). Формального запрета на циклические конструкторы в спецификации нет.

Comment: @PetSerAl, ок, спасибо. Как мне подсказали, об этом даже Jon Skeet писал: [VIOLATING THE “SMART ENUM” PATTERN IN C#](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/10/23/violating-the-smart-enum-pattern-in-c/)